# Define $g(x)=xf(x)$. If $f$ is continuous at $0$, then prove that $g$ is differentiable at $0$.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity, solution-verification

> Given $f\colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and define $g\colon\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $g(x)=xf(x)$. If $f$ is continuous at $0$, then prove that $g$ is differentiable at $0$ with $g'(0)=f(0)$.

**Here's my attempt:**

We know that if $f(x)$ is continuous at $0$, then $g(x)$ is continuous at $0$, because multiplication of $x$ and $f(x)$ again a continuous function. It follows that:
\begin{align}
g(0)=0
\end{align}
Also, because we know that $f$ is continuous at $x=0$:
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to\ 0} f(x)=f(0) 
\\ \lim_{x\to\ 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}(x-0) \end{align}
That means $f$ also differentiable, so by knowing $x$ and $f(x)$ are differentiable we can say $g(x)$ is also differentiable at $x=0$. If we take the derivative at the definition of the function we get
\begin{align}
g'(0)=f(0)
\end{align}
Is it true logic? Or does it make sense? Thanks for helping.

Comment: $f$  need not be differentiable at $0$. Look at the limit definition for $g'(0)$.

Comment: Are you sure you mean "define $g(x) = x$? That makes no connection with $f$.

Comment: But I proved that $\lim_{x\to\ 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}(x-0)$

Comment: Did I write it wrong? it is $g(x)=x.f(x)$

Comment: @beingmathematician Um I found that out after 10 seconds I post the comment. Usually you write the multiplication of two functions like $g(x) = xf(x)$, there usually won't be a $.$ in it.

Comment: Proved what about it?

Comment: If you want to use a dot for multiplication, use `\cdot`.  `$x\cdot f(x)$` appears as $x\cdot f(x)$

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped so much. I've edited the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't need a complicated argument regarding continuity of $g$ to conclude that $g(0)=0$, you can simply substitute
$$g(0) = 0 \cdot f(0) = 0
$$
But the main problem with your proof is that in order to determine whether $g'(0)$ exists, you must write out the difference quotient $\frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x-0}$ and simplify it and try to find its limit as $x \to 0$. I do not see anywhere in your solution that you have written out the different quotient.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped!

Answer (score 1):

No, in the middle of your argument you conclude that $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$, but $f$ is only assumed to be continuous at $x=0$.

Hint.

Study the quotient
$$
\frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x-0}=\frac{xf(x)}{x}
$$
and use the continuity of $f$ at $x=0$.

Comment: Oh I see, I attempted that but I couldn't be sure thanks a lot!